# Nano can not find previous occurrence while searching with alt+Q shortcut

Tags: terminal, nano

I was trying to find a text with nano. Ctrl+W shows the text and with alt+W I can go the next occurrence but when I try to go to the previous occurrence with alt+Q, I see a message

```
 Conversion of typed tabs to spaces disabled
```

How do I disable this shortcut so that I can go to the previous occurrence with alt+Q?

Answer (score 0):

Check the ~/.nanorc, if there is a `bind M-Q ...` string - remove it.

Or, if the binding is done in a system wide /etc/nanorc, then you can add `unbind` to the local `~/.nanorc`

Latest versions are also reading configs from:

```
System-wide configuration file.
  /etc/nanorc
Per-user configuration file.
  ~/.nanorc or $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nano/nanorc or ~/.config/nano/nanorc
```

It could be useful to look here: https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.9/nanorc.5.html and https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/cheatsheet.html